# PHP look up value by key given a list of objects

Tags: php, json

I have this JSON data that is set up as an array of objects that looks like this, where the keys are literally called "key" and the values are literally called "value":

```
$fruit = [{"key": "a", "value": "apple"}, 
          {"key": "b", "value": "banana"},
          {"key": "c", "value": "cherry"}];
```

I am trying to write a PHP function that takes in this array as an argument, along with the key I want to look up.

The function should act as a lookup so that the function will return the value associated with the provided key. For example:

```
function lookup($array, $key){

   // look through the list of objects and 
   // return value that is associated with this key 
}
```

Example function call:

`lookup($fruit, "c");`

Expected output:

`"cherry"`

I am new to PHP, so I don't know if PHP has a best practice or native function that would make easy work of this, or should I iterate through the $fruit array and build a new PHP array with it first? What is the best way to do this?

Comment: How do you get this JSON data? While it seems valid, it seems like a weird way to do what you are trying to do.

Comment: I know. The JSON input data is formatted that way unfortunately. The format is not ideal but I have no control over it, which is why I am trying to create a lookup function.

Comment: What to return if the key isn't found?

Comment: vivek_23, if key is not found, return empty string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using PHP 7.0+ you can use [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) on an array of objects.

Providing the second argument as the property name to retrieve values from, and then using the third argument to specify the property name to index by, will provide you with a full list of values indexed by the specified key.

### Example https://3v4l.org/vJcmH

```
$values = array_column($json, 'value', 'key');

var_dump($values);
/*
 array(3) {
  ["a"]=>
  string(5) "apple"
  ["b"]=>
  string(6) "banana"
  ["c"]=>
  string(6) "cherry"
}
*/

var_dump($values['c']);
/*
  string(6) "cherry"
 */
```

### Function usage https://3v4l.org/8TMBf

```
/**
 * @param array|object[] $json
 * @param string $key
 * @param mixed $default
 * @param string $column
 * @param string $index
 * @return string
 */
function lookup($json, $key, $default = '', $column = 'value', $index = 'key') {
    return array_column($json, $column, $index)[$key] ?? $default;
}

var_dump(lookup($json, 'c'));
```

**Result:**

```
string(6) "cherry"
```

> Note, this will return a single value, if you are expecting to have
>   more than 1 result with the same `key` property value, this approach
>   will not yield expected results. If so please let me know and I will update my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Convert your JSON string to a PHP array

```
$fruit = json_decode($fruit, true);
lookup($fruit, 'key');
```

Then, you just have to loop through the array in your function.

```
function lookup($array, $key) {

    //loop through all values in array
    foreach($array as $values) {

        //if 'key' value matches `$key`, return 'value' value.
        if($values['key'] == $key) {
            return $values['value'];
        }

    }

    //if nothing has been returned, return empty string
    return "";
}
```

Now, if you have control over creating the `$fruit` value, it would be better to create it in this pattern:

```
$fruit = [
    "a" => "apple",
    "b" => "banana",
    "c" => "cherry",
];
```

then you can access it with:

```
$fruit[$key];
```

Comment: or just if(isset($values['key'])) {

Comment: @RobertSinclair I'm sorry, what?

Comment: Instead of  if($values['key'] == $key) { -> if(isset($values[$key])) {

Comment: @RobertSinclair Is there some performance gain from this? Readability wise, I definitely don't prefer it

Comment: @RobertSinclair since the structure is `$values = ['key' => 'a', 'value' => 'apple']` you would need to check `$values['key'] === 'a'` Since `isset($values['a'])` would return `false`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work.

https://ideone.com/94Uxby

```
<?php

$fruit = json_decode($sourceOfJson, true);

function lookup($array, $key){
    // Find the index of the entry where "key" = $key
    $index = array_search($key, array_column($array, 'key'));

    // Handle the entry not being found however you want to.
    if(!$index){
        return null;
        // throw new Exception("Couldn't find index from value $key");
        // Log::error("Couldn't find index from value $key");
        // return 'SomeDefaultValue';
    }

    return $array[$index]['value'];
}

echo lookup($fruit, 'c');
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have any control over the format of the incoming JSON array. I have to work around the fact that it is set up as an array of objects..

Comment: @ChrisNielsen Then, how is it setup in your code? Can you `var_export($fruit)` from your PHP code and show us what you get?

Comment: @vivek_23: When I do var_export as you said, this is what I get:

```array ( 0 => array ( 'key' => 'a', 'value' => 'apple', ), 
        1 => array ( 'key' => 'b', 'value' => 'banana', ), 
        2 => array ( 'key' => 'c', 'value' => 'cherry', ), )```

Comment: @ChrisNielsen So, it is the same as what the current answer suggests. When you say you don't have control over the incoming JSON array, you can't really parse it from a single code source unless you are aware of it's limited possible representations.

Comment: The issue is only that `$array[$index]` would be an object. So `$array[$index]['value']` should be converted to `$array[$index]->value` or `((array) $array[$index])['value']` https://3v4l.org/Q33EN Additionally it should be `false === $index`, since index can be `0`, as in the case of `lookup($fruit, 'a')`, which would return `null` currently.